# Logging out Azure Ad web application logs out Office365 in browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have used Azure AD for login in my website. So that user is redirected to the Office365 page for login. I have used OpenIdConnect authentication. The login option works fine. But signing out in my website, the Office365 openned in my browser also signs out. Is this the correct behavior? If I want only my website to sign out, what i have to do?

Thanks in advance.

Dinesh.

Comment: common behaviour is you have to sign out your website alone not the office 365 site.

Comment: I figured out that enabling the single sign out option will sign out all the Office365 related application. Is there any way to disable the single sign out option ?